# Shrink sticky header on scroll with image and text, without javascript

Tags: html, css, image

I have a project where I need to make a sticky header, like the picture shown below. So a 'front page' with an image as background, with a title and description. When scrolled the picture will be cropped and the description will be gone.

[image]

I am not allowed to use javascript. I was thinking about making the smaller header behind the big one, so when I am scrolling they just switch positions. But it seems like bad practice. I know the best way is to use js, just wondering how it can be done without!

```css
html,
body {
    margin: 0;
}


header {
    background-color: yellow;
    background-image: url(../image/titel_image.jpeg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;

    text-align: center;

    width: 100%;
    height: 50vh;

    position: absolute;
    top: 0;

    z-index: 99;
}

.box {
    background-color: white;

    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.box-nav {
    background-color: yellow;
    background-image: url(../image/titel_image.jpeg);
    /* background-attachment: fixed; */
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;

    text-align: center;

    width: 100%;
    height: 10vh;

    position: sticky;
    top: 0;

    z-index: 98;

    margin-top: -20rem;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
}

main {
    margin-top: 30rem;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="box">
            <h1>Title</h1>
            <h2>Description:</h2>
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</p>
        </div>
    </header>

    <main>
        <div class="box-nav">
            <h1>Title</h1>
        </div>

        <section>
            <h2>The problem:</h2>
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</p>
        </section>
        
        <section>
            <h2>The problem:</h2>
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</p>
        </section>

    </main>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a step by step that may help you accomplish what you need to do.

https://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-a-shrinking-header-on-scroll-without-javascript/

Comment: I found this aswell, but it still gets me stuck on the description part

Comment: your code is working. https://codepen.io/MrLister-the-bashful/pen/NWMVgLM

Comment: Not exactly sure what you mean for the description part.

Comment: In the first drawing, i have a description, but when scrolling, that is going to disappear so only the title is left at the top

Comment: That is what it is doing. Look at my code pen link.

Comment: I'm trying something similar, but i want to have a logo that fits the height of the outer nav bar. Is there a no-js way of having the contents inside shrink with the header on scroll  that isn't just a visual trick?